# Generalising a C++ templated function so it can accept std::reference_wrapper or non-wrapped type of N elements

Tags: c++, reference-wrapper

I have a function that accepts N position vectors and updates them:

```cpp
using Vector3r = Eigen::Matrix<Real, 3, 1, Eigen::DontAlign>;
template<unsigned int N>
using Vectorr = Eigen::Matrix<Real, N, 1, Eigen::DontAlign>;

template <unsigned int N>
bool solveFbd(const std::reference_wrapper<Vector3r> (&positions)[N]);
```

The force

I have another function that accepts N position vectors and gives the force

```cpp
template <unsigned int N>
void forceInternal(const std::reference_wrapper<Vector3r> (&positions)[N], Vectorr<N*3>& forces);
```

Until now I was simply passing the positions parameter inside `solveFbd` as an argument to a `forceInternal` call.

```cpp
forceInternal(positions);
```

I copied the type parameter of parameter `position` for `forceInternal` from `solveFbd` blindly, however I don't modify `positions` in this so it should have ideally been `const std::reference_wrapper<const Vector3r> (&positions)[N]`. Unfortunately adding this extra `const` gives me errors with this call. If there is some way to do convert the positions to `std::reference_wrapper<const Vector3r> (&positions)[N]` it would greatly help but it is not the main problem I am facing here.

Now, I also need to do something like this:

```cpp
Vector3r positionsCopy[N];
Vectorr<3*N> forces;
for (unsigned int p = 0; p < N; p++)
{
    // I need to make a copy here, I can't change that original `positions`
    positionsCopy[p] = positions[p] + delta[p];
}
forceInternal(positionsCopy, forces);
```

Unfortunately I get this error when the function `solveFbd` is instantiated with template parameter `3u`:

```
C:\Users\sin3point14\my-projs\gpbd\PositionBasedDynamics\FBD.cpp(581): error C2664: '_Ret std::_Func_class<_Ret,const std::reference_wrapper<Vector3r> (&)[3],Eigen::Matrix<Real,9,1,2,9,1> &>::operator ()(const std::reference_wrapper<Vector3r> (&)[3],Eigen::Matrix<Real,9,1,2,9,1> &) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Vector3r [3]' to 'const std::reference_wrapper<Vector3r> (&)[3]'
        with
        [
            _Ret=void
        ]
C:\Users\sin3point14\my-projs\gpbd\PositionBasedDynamics\FBD.cpp(581): note: Reason: cannot convert from 'Vector3r [3]' to 'const std::reference_wrapper<Vector3r> [3]'
C:\Users\sin3point14\my-projs\gpbd\PositionBasedDynamics\FBD.cpp(581): note: There is no context in which this conversion is possible
```

From the error I understood that the conversion isn't possible, but I don't want to make a separate overload for `forceInternal` to accept `Vector3r [3]`. There are many such `forceInternal` functions for different force models in my codebase. Is it possible to somehow modify my existing `solveFbd` or `forceInternal` to handle my problem.

minimal reproducible example:

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>

using Real = double;

using Vector3r = Eigen::Matrix<Real, 3, 1, Eigen::DontAlign>;
template<unsigned int N>
using Vectorr = Eigen::Matrix<Real, N, 1, Eigen::DontAlign>;

template <unsigned int N>
void forceInternal(const std::reference_wrapper<Vector3r>(&positions)[N], Vectorr<N * 3>& forces)
{
    // do some stuff
}

template <unsigned int N>
bool solveFbd(const std::reference_wrapper<Vector3r>(&positions)[N])
{
    Vectorr<N * 3> forces;
    forceInternal(positions, forces); // no issues here
    Vector3r positionsCopy[N];
    Vector3r delta[N];
    for (unsigned int p = 0; p < N; p++)
    {
        // I need to make a copy here, I can't change that original `positions`
        positionsCopy[p] = positions[p].get() + delta[p];
    }
    forceInternal(positionsCopy, forces); // error
}

int main()
{
    Vector3r x1, x2, x3;
    solveFbd({ x1, x2, x3 });
}
```

Error:

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication4, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>ConsoleApplication4.cpp
1>C:\Users\sin3point14\my-projs\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4.cpp(27,5): error C2672: 'forceInternal': no matching overloaded function found
1>C:\Users\sin3point14\my-projs\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4.cpp(10,6): message : could be 'void forceInternal(const std::reference_wrapper<Vector3r> (&)[N],Eigen::Matrix<Real,N*3,1,2,_Rows,1> &)'
1>C:\Users\sin3point14\my-projs\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4.cpp(27,5): message : 'void forceInternal(const std::reference_wrapper<Vector3r> (&)[N],Eigen::Matrix<Real,N*3,1,2,_Rows,1> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reference_wrapper<Vector3r> (&)[N]' from 'Vector3r [3]'
1>C:\Users\sin3point14\my-projs\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4.cpp(33,2): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool solveFbd<3>(const std::reference_wrapper<Vector3r> (&)[3])' being compiled
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplication4.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 5:55 PM and took 01.610 seconds ==========
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the function template accept arrays of any type:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int N>
void forceInternal(const T(&positions)[N], Vectorr<N * 3>& forces)
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

If necessary you can add constraints that `T` must be either `td::reference_wrapper<Vector3r>` or `Vector3r`.

You miss to return a value from `solveFbd`. After fixing that your code looks ok: https://godbolt.org/z/Ts4TMbfK7